# radioButton dase not stop adding the value when is clicked

Tags: java, android

I'm making a quiz app on Android Studio. I have a group of radioButtons, but the problem is that when I check a `radiobutton` and click on it when is already checked  the radioButton  keeps stacking the value over and over again. I just want to add the value once, when is checked even if I click on it when is already check it should not keep adding nothing this is my method code for the radioButton.

```
 public void firstAnswer(View view) {

    boolean checked = ((RadioButton) view).isChecked();


    switch (view.getId()) {

        case R.id.firstAnswer_question1:

            if (checked) {
                radioButtonQuestionOneScore = radioButtonQuestionOneScore + 12.50;
                break;
            } else {
                radioButtonQuestionOneScore = 0;
            }
            break;

        case R.id.secondAnswer_question1:

            if (checked)
                break;

        case R.id.thirdAnswer_question1:

            if (checked)
                break;

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

better you can go with CheckBox, RadioButton doesn't provide any default property for your problem, else you have to design Custom RadioButton.